# Can (and should) I copy the answers from this similar question on another stack?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272130/why-does-the-joker-have-such-high-pain-tolerance) question has answers on the Movies and TV stack exchange, So can I and should I copy the answer from there and post it to this question here?

Link to mentioned [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/in-the-dark-knight-why-does-the-joker-not-appear-to-feel-any-pain)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take any content from anywhere on the internet for use in your own answer. However, the normal rules for plagiarism and [how to properly reference content](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) apply:

> If you copy (or closely rephrase/reword) content that you did not create into something you post on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange (e.g., from another site or elsewhere on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange), make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author
>
> This ensures that the original creator gets credit for their work.

However, it is worth noting that if all you're going to do is copy an answer word for word as a quote and that's it then it will be liable for deletion.

> Do *not* copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

As the help article says the best best is to phrase something in your own words and use quotes from the source to back up your ideas.

I will say that quoting someone else's opinion on something isn't really a good source though. Ideally you should use the primary source (in this case the comics, films, shows, etc.) as evidence instead.

Answer (score 5):

TheLethalCarrot's [excellent answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13862/20774) addresses the question of whether you *can* copy answers from this question, so I'll focus on whether you *should* (spoiler, no you shouldn't).

To my mind, none of the answers [posted on the other site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/in-the-dark-knight-why-does-the-joker-not-appear-to-feel-any-pain) seem especially authoritative:

- The top answer is simply an assertion that his pain threshold is due to his insanity. No evidence (whatsoever) is offered to back this up.
- The second answer has information copied and pasted from a fan-written wiki page, but again no primary sources
- The third answer is a total guess

I can't speak for other users, but if they were posted here, I would immediately downvote them for the reasons above. Historically we've shown more keenness for [answers with primary sources](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/primary-sources-vs-wikis/1346#1346).

Comment: I realized in time that the answer wasn't good afterall, and just because it was accepted wouldn't make it a good authoritative answer

Answer (score 5):

On [the occasion I did](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/113219/9382), I quoted the entire answer, linked to the original, and marked it community wiki.

I think this is acceptable as well, since it *is* a community effort: the original answerer provided the answer, and you found it and reposted it.